# How to write a Munit test case for an integration that is using a common HTTP request connector for calling 5 different resources of the system layer?

Tags: mulesoft, mule-esb, mule4, munit

I am calling a system layer from process layer as

first get: /abc
get: /xyz
post: /efg
for all these 3 calls using a common http requestor by setting path, method and host before calling this http requestor.

how to mock this http requestor for each call that give me different responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add 3 mock when's to your Munit. Each of them will have the processor 'http:request', but with attributes specific to the call. So in each mock you will provide the AttributeName="method" and AttributeName="path" where the values correspond to the specific call you want to mock. See an example of two mocks below.

```
<munit-tools:mock-when doc:name="Mock when POST" doc:id="8e3b66fe-b5bb-4f96-97b5-8970c1635b12" processor="http:request">
    <munit-tools:with-attributes >
        <munit-tools:with-attribute whereValue="POST" attributeName="method" />
        <munit-tools:with-attribute whereValue="/post" attributeName="path" />
    </munit-tools:with-attributes>
    <munit-tools:then-return >
        <munit-tools:payload value='#[{"data": "post"}]' mediaType="application/json" />
    </munit-tools:then-return>
</munit-tools:mock-when>
<munit-tools:mock-when doc:name="Mock when GET" doc:id="4797dd50-8bc2-428a-9aba-7d03692fc1a2" processor="http:request" >
    <munit-tools:with-attributes >
        <munit-tools:with-attribute whereValue="GET" attributeName="method" />
        <munit-tools:with-attribute whereValue="/get" attributeName="path" />
    </munit-tools:with-attributes>
    <munit-tools:then-return >
        <munit-tools:payload value='#[{"data": "get"}]' mediaType="application/json" />
    </munit-tools:then-return>
</munit-tools:mock-when>
```

Comment: Hello @WijnandG thank you for your answer.

Here one query is if we use the same method also and the same resource then what will we do?